# Что такое CMS, то есть система управления сайтом?

Tags: joomla, php, cms

Что такое CMS, то есть система управления сайтом? Я читал в гугле и википедии, но не понял, для чего нужен joomla. По возможности дайте ссылку, где можно скачать эту библиотеку.

Answer (score 5):

Грамотно поставленный вопрос - как минимум половина ответа! Вот вы сами себе и ответили на свой "вопрос". Выходит, что CMS - это система управления сайтом!

Answer (score 1):

CMS это система управления сайтом. Есть много платных и бесплатных... Т.е. устанавливаешь систему, задаешё шаблоны и чего ты хочешь, а она это всё делает, особенно хорошо тем, кто не силён в программировании. Есть много видеоуроков например Евгений Попов.....Александр Куртеев - по системе Jomala. Так же битрикс и другие системы/

Если что, искать можно на rutracker.org или на любом другом торрент трекере.